# JENKINS_HOME string getting appended after resolving to actual in powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am using `%JENKINS_HOME%` inside my powershell script, but in jenkins it is getting resolved to the actual path with `%JENKINS_HOME%` getting appended.

for example: I am using

```
cd "%JENKINS_HOME%"
```

and what in actual is happening is

```
cd C:\Users\Vedant\.jenkins\jobs\my_job\%JENKINS_HOME%
```

Comment: Have you read yet any docs about environment variable usage in Powershell?

Comment: @vonPryz sorry to respond so late. I was new to Powershell and I read the docs after seeing your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$env:JENKINS_HOME
```

Comment: to top of the script file? and replace it with only JENKINS_HOME

Comment: Powershell uses its own syntax which is different from command line. You will have to change %JENKINS_HOME% to $env:JENKINS_HOME in your powershell script.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!